# sleep doesn't work on Ubuntu 20.04 (WSL)

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, 20.04

After upgrading to 20.04 on WSL sleep doesn't work with an error:

```
sleep: cannot read realtime clock: Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because of a bug in WSL1. Look here:
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-20-04-and-wsl-1/15291

> The upcoming Ubuntu 20.04 implements glibc 2.31. Unless you are on Insider you have not gotten the fix for issue 4989 yet and likely will not for a couple months. Without the fix things tend to break on Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL 1, sometimes even in the upgrade process 9 to Ubuntu 20.04. For example htop doesn’t work on Ubuntu 20.04 on unpatched WSL 1.

Answer (score 23):

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~rafaeldtinoco/+archive/ubuntu/lp1871129/+files/libc6_2.31-0ubuntu8+lp1871129~1_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg --install libc6_2.31-0ubuntu8+lp1871129~1_amd64.deb

sudo apt-mark hold libc6

sudo apt --fix-broken install

sudo apt full-upgrade
```

**[How to upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 on WSL Windows 10](https://www.how2shout.com/how-to/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-18-04-lts-to-20-04-lts-on-wsl-windows-10.html)**

Comment: It seems that many of your answers consists the link https://www.how2shout.com. If you're the owner of that domain, please disclose your affiliation. See [How to not be a spammer](https://askubuntu.com/help/promotion).

Comment: Isn't a good idea to run `sudo apt-mark unhold libc6` at the end?

Comment: I'd prefer if this answer explained what that random `.deb` package is and what the risks are of installing it and whether (and how) it would be easy to revert back later.

Answer (score 15):

Just had this problem and I replaced the `/usr/bin/sleep` binary with a python script that roughly replaces the functionality.

Backup `/usr/bin/sleep` and replace with the file with the following contents

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import time

time.sleep(int(sys.argv[1]))
```

Remember to `chmod +x /usr/bin/sleep` after replacing.

Comment: `sudo cp -p /usr/bin/sleep /usr/bin/sleep.orig` and `sudo vim /usr/bin/sleep` were helpful commands for me. I think your hack might be working for me, although in my Windows Task Manager, I see a php7.4 background process with "Very high" for "Power usage", and I don't know why.

Comment: I needed to replace `/bin/sleep` instead, on my ubuntu installation.

Comment: https://github.com/u-root/u-root/blob/master/cmds/core/sleep/sleep.go

I used this instead as I needed support for seconds/minutes etc.

Answer (score 2):

This command worked for me. use with root user privilege.

```
apt-mark hold libc6
apt --fix-broken install
apt full-upgrade
```

Comment: Those 3 commands didn't work for me until I prepended `sudo ` to each, and only after running `sudo apt-get update`. Then they seemed to solve this problem. So I guess I'll +1.

Comment: Actually, I don't think it worked for me, but I can't remove my upvote. Currently I'm hoping https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230252/sleep-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-20-04-wsl#comment2160590_1253473 works.

Answer (score 1):

It's far from ideal but another workaround is to edit `/var/lib/dpkg/info/libc6:amd64.postinst` and comment out the `set -e` at the top of the script (insert a `#` as the first character in the line).

You will still receive the `sleep: cannot read realtime clock: Invalid argument` error but it will not cause the upgrade of the package to abort.

It's not ideal because:

1. A standard post-install script is modified.
2. The script change must be applied every time `libc6` is upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

Using read as alternative workaround

```
sudo cp -p /usr/bin/sleep /usr/bin/sleep.orig
echo 'read -n1 -s -t$1 || true' | sudo tee /usr/bin/sleep
```

Comment: This looked interesting, but I got an error: `sudo service supervisor start
Starting supervisor: /bin/sleep: 1: read: Illegal option -n`

Answer (score -1):

Installing this via dpkg on the Surface Pro X solved it for me,
https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/19.10/ubuntu-updates-main-arm64/libc6_2.30-0ubuntu2.2_arm64.deb.html

After install I ran wsl -t Ubuntu in PowerShell then sudo apt-mark hold libc6.

Answer (score -2):

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 using WSL 1 (my windows 10 version is 1903, OS Build 18362.778) and got this error trying to run a redis server.

Thanks to Raj's link to https://www.how2shout.com/how-to/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-18-04-lts-to-20-04-lts-on-wsl-windows-10.html I got it fixed using what it suggested there.

```
sudo -i
sudo mv /bin/sleep /bin/sleep~ ; touch /bin/sleep ; chmod +x /bin/sleep
```

After that the redis server ran ok.

Comment: ... Doesn't that just replace `/bin/sleep` with an empty file? This is a terrible hack and is bound to break things in unexpected ways.

Comment: Yeah, it may get you past some sticky situations, but sleep is a standard UNIX command and no doubt just replacing it with an empty file that does nothing is going to screw up a lot of things.