# Ubuntu 20.04 broken updates libc6

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, dpkg

in my WSL1, I update Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04 from Microsoft Store.
So I run the command sudo **do-release-upgrade** and it says to change /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades from Prompt=LTS to Prompt=Normal.
Then I could update to Ubuntu 19.10 but during the process I get the error for Snap Store and I Skip it and after finish update, I run **sudo dpkg --force depends -P lxd** and **sudo dpkg --force depends -P lxd-client**. After that update and upgrade process run correctly.

Then I found the command **sudo do-release-upgrade -d** to force the update of Ubuntu 20.04 and after that I had some errors and when I run commands for update and upgrade I have this error message:

```
~$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.31) but 2.31-0ubuntu9 is installed
 locales : Depends: libc-bin (> 2.31) but 2.30-0ubuntu2.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I run **sudo apt --fix-broken install** and it can't do anything and return errors.

Someone could help me?
Thanks

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc-bin libc6 locales`?

Comment: What does `sudo apt-get install -f` tell? And `sudo dpkg --configure -a`?

Comment: `apt-cache policy libc-bin` please. for a long shot `sudo apt install --reinstall libc-bin=2.31-0ubuntu9`

Comment: this article contains the fix https://askubuntu.com/a/1232422/1115053

Answer (score 0):

At last I reinstall WSL and Ubuntu and all errors gone.
Thanks to all.

Hope this post will be helpful in future