# sleep() function in C doesn't work on Ubuntu 20.04 (WSL). Is there any way to make the sleep() work?

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux, c

I am using a Windows app for Ubuntu to practice C/C++ code.

Eventually I found that `sleep()` call does not work here. I went through the answers provided earlier on other posts but could not find any relevant solution for it.

So I just want to know whether there is any way to make `sleep()` or a similar kind of waiting call to work on same Ubuntu application?

Example code:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<signal.h>

void handler(int num)
{
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, "I am in handler...handling signal\n", 13);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        signal(SIGINT, handler);
        signal(SIGTERM,handler);

        while(1)
        {
                printf("Just wasting your time! PID = %d\n", getpid());
                sleep(1);
        }

}
```

Comment: [sleep doesn't work on Ubuntu 20.04 (WSL)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230252/sleep-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-20-04-wsl/1262933#1262933)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`sleep()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sleeping.html) is a system call. In WSL 1 the instructions are *translated* and further handled by Windows NT kernel since WSL 1 doesn't consist of a *real* Linux kernel. On the other hand, WSL 2 consists of a *real* Linux kernel built by Microsoft based on the Linux kernel's source code and thus handle system calls.

For your reference this is an overview of WSL 1 architecture:

[image: WSL 1 architecture]

And this is an overview of WSL 2 architecture:

[image: WSL 2 architecture]
<sup>**Image credits**: [What is Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL and WSL2)? — Linux in Windows - FOSSBYTES](https://fossbytes.com/what-is-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl/)</sup>

So, there's no guarantee that all system calls specific to Linux kernel are translated and will be understood by Windows NT kernel.

To make `sleep()` work, you need to use *real* Linux kernel, i.e., WSL 2. To see which WSL version you're currently using, open command prompt or Powershell and run

```
wsl -l -v
```

This would list all distributions you're currently using with the WSL version and state. To switch WSL versions run

```bsh
wsl --set-version distributionName WSLversion # eg:  wsl --set-version ubuntu-20.04 2
```

You might need to install *the kernel* first. You can refer to [Update to WSL 2 - Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#update-to-wsl-2).

---

On a lighter note, `sleep()` takes time in milliseconds as an argument and 1 ms is very less to be noticed. I suggest trying with at least 15000 ms, i.e., 15 seconds.

---

#### Relevant topics:

- [WSL System Calls - Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/wsl/wsl-system-calls)
- [Windows Subsystem for Linux Overview - Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/wsl/windows-subsystem-for-linux-overview)
- [What's New in WSL 2? - Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-index)
- [Comparing WSL 1 and WSL 2 - Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions)
- [What is Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL and WSL2)? — Linux in Windows - FOSSBYTES](https://fossbytes.com/what-is-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl/)

Comment: Thanks. This information is really useful and relevant.